# How to generate reveal.js slides from pandoc programmatically?

Tags: haskell, pandoc, reveal.js, hakyll

I am using [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll) to generate my blog and would like to integrate in the generated web site some slides from talks I give. This should be as simple as defining you own custom `pandocCompiler` with adequate configuration and indeed I manage to do it.

Here is the compiler definition:

```
 pandocSlideCompiler :: Compiler (Item String)
 pandocSlideCompiler = pandocCompilerWith defaultHakyllReaderOptions writeHtmlSlide
   where
     writeHtmlSlide = defaultHakyllWriterOptions { writerIncremental = True
                                                 , writerSectionDivs = False
                                                 , writerVariables = [("theme", "beige")]
                                                 , writerSlideLevel = Just 2
                                                 , writerSlideVariant = RevealJsSlides
                                                 , writerIgnoreNotes = True
                                                 }
```

This works but the generated slides are not correctly formatted: Each slide is generated as `div` whereas reveal.js expects a `section`.

Here is the command-line equivalent I would like to implement:

```
pandoc --slide-level 2 --variable theme=beige -i -s -o slides.html --template=template-revealjs.html -t revealjs slides.md
```

My question is then: Which options from [Text.Pandoc.Options](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.17.0.3/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html) shall I use to produce the same result as my command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `writerHtml5 = True`, as can be seen in the pandoc source [commandline args parsing](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/676b800993fffcc0e2ba44c88cfb6d552a37a136/src/Text/Pandoc.hs#L292) and [HTML writer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/09b4f294bf4584f0010abc331b7e44bb26189865/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs#L316)...

Comment: This answer requires an update for year 2021.